# match exact the pending amount with settlement

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have two table which @pending table is a pending fund table waiting for settlement, @settle table is to settle this @pending but required match the exact full amount(value) of each record. but i cannot figure out how to perform this task. anyone have idea.

```
declare @pending as table (id int, value decimal(18,4))
declare @settle as table (id int, value decimal(18,4))

insert into @pending (id, value) values (1, 500)
insert into @pending (id, value) values (2, 250)
insert into @pending (id, value) values (3, 100)
insert into @pending (id, value) values (4, 250)

insert into @settle (id, value) values (1,500)
insert into @settle (id, value) values (2,300)
insert into @settle (id, value) values (3,200)
```

expect result:
record below will not match

```
insert into @pending (id, value) values (3, 100)
```

record below have to match

```
insert into @pending (id, value) values (1, 500)
insert into @pending (id, value) values (2, 250)
insert into @pending (id, value) values (4, 250)

insert into @settle (id, value) values (1,500)
insert into @settle (id, value) values (2,300)
insert into @settle (id, value) values (3,200)

   row | pending_id | pending_value | pending_bal | match_amount | settle_id 
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    1       1              500           0             500           1           
    2       2              250           0             250           2          
    3       4              250           200            50           2
    4       4              250           0             200           3
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: sorry i had edited the question. actually i want to ask how to perform this matching query.

Answer (score 0):

You could join on the value columns:

```
SELECT p.id, p.value, s.id, s.value
FROM   @pending p
JOIN   @settle s ON p.value = s.value
```

Comment: hi, your query is only return the first match, expected result for row 2 to 4 is not return.